# Azure Queues: How to determing when the message invisibility timeout going to expire

Tags: azure, azure-storage-queues, azure-storage

In Azure Queues, Is there a way to find out when the message invisibility timeout going to expire. I want to check to see if the timeout's going to expire and extend if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using storage client library for .Net, When you get messages using [`GetMessages()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueue.getmessages.aspx), the message objects should have [`NextVisibleTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.queue.cloudqueuemessage.nextvisibletime.aspx) field populated. You could use this property to find out when a message's timeout is going to expire and the message will be visible again.